# Is the use of « ça » here considered optional, informal, and emphatic?

Tags: pronoms

I mean, when using the construction « je trouve (ça) + adjectif + de ... »?

> 1 : Je trouve juste **ça** mignon de te voir comme ça, sur la défensive.

I wonder:

- if including « ça » is optional,
- if « ça » makes the sentence sound more informal,
- if « ça » adds an emphasis.

Incidentally, in the case of the verb « penser », I assume you cannot include « ça » under any circumstances.

> 2 : Je pensais {(**x**) **ça**} préférable de ne le dire à personne, mais ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's optional, very optional, not needed at all.
Yes, it sounds more informal, but because *"ça"* is an informal "cela". With "cela", it doesn't sound as informal.
The first purpose is probably to emphasize but it's so common that it does not.

You are right, with *penser* it sounds strange.

Answer (score 1):

- > Je trouve juste mignon de te voir comme ça, sur la défensive.

  and

  > Je pensais préférable de ne le dire à personne, mais ...

  are fine and correct in French.

   The meaning is the same than without.
- *ça* is an abbreviate form of *cela*, so it will sound less formal.
- It underlines the adjective you are using after rather than the sub clause (what the adjective qualifies).

---

I am not sure about what you are talking about mentioning the *penser* verb.
There can be sentences where you use *penser* and you cannot use *ça*.

> Je pense à toi.

But you **have to** use it with the structure `penser + ça + adjective + de + subclause`.

Comment: Side note: "Je ne pensais pas ça de toi" doesn't fit your last rule (no adjective) ;)

Comment: @Random You are right ! The fact is that there, *ça* carry the adjective meaning. `Tu es grossier. Je ne pensais pas ça de toi.`.

Comment: La partie sur *penser* ne répond pas à sa question. Sa question porte sur l'utilisation de *ça* dans une phrase qui est sur le modèle : sujet + verbe de sentiment/d'avis + adjectif + *de* suivi de ce que tu veux exprimer. *"Je trouve dommage de partir maintenant"* / *"je trouve **ça** dommage de partir maintenant"*. Avec les verbes *penser* ou *estimer*, par exemple, l'utilisation de *ça* ne sonne pas bien (quoique à force d'y réfléchir, ça me dérange moins).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence, with two "ça" is informal, spoken language, I would avoid it (I'm French).

Answer (score 0):

Pose toi juste la question, si on change la position de (**ça**) et qu'on mette une expression du même sens, est-ce que tout le sens de la phrase va changer ? La réponse est Non, rien ne changera , exemple :

> Je trouve juste mignon **le fait** de te voir comme ça, sur la défensive.

-La question qui se pose ici est (**quoi**) ? qu'est ce que tu trouves mignon ? et le (**ça**) répond à la question !

-Encore une chose si on décide de s'arrêter à l'adjectif **Mignon**, la phrase sera moins claire et plus agrammaticale :

> Je trouve juste mignon. (L'adverbe -juste- précise l'adjectif)

-D'un autre côté si on dit :

> Je trouve juste ça mignon. (L'adverbe -juste- précise le pronom démonstratif)

-La phrase aurait plus de sens et elle serait plus grammaticale que la précédente. Le pronom démonstratif (**ça**) apporte plus d'information et de précision !

Comment: "Je trouve juste mignon" n'est pas correct - il manque quelque chose - on ne sait pas en l'occurence quel chose on trouve "mignonne".

Comment: @Frank c'est pour ça que j'ai dit plus "agrammaticale" (contraire aux normes de la grammaire) !